# Group records from a set by a common value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with groping a set of records by a common value.  A common value isn't one single value thought therefore I'm not sure how to approach it

This is a set / table:

[image]

This is what I'd need to achieve:

[image]

Is it too tricky or it could be achieved (SQL 2012). If it could please point me into a direction coz I'm hit a bit wall :D Thanks!

Comment: Post the sample data and expected result as table format in question instead of Image

Comment: Why is "Gibraltar MDR" mapped to "MDR" and not "Gibraltar"?  What if you had "WaterLup MDR"?  Your rules are too vague.

Comment: Bad output, you want to group the records which are not at the right position. You need to make the rootcompany name same or you need another column which can give you reliable values to group by.

Comment: Yep, maybe to vague, you are right.  Though nor sure how to specify it.  I'm looking to find a string in each row, column Company Name that could be common in any other row... 
 
As per MDR; is a common string in CompnayID 6 and 7.  User decided to put a value of a location prior to a company name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use disctinct form when you get group data from specific column

```
 SELECT DISTINCT SSC FROM Table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh!  Perhaps I've asked a wrong question but not sure how distinct could help me here, Suresh.   I'd need to find a commons string in a Company name column to change the Root company one.  Company Name differs quite a lot though however, each row may contain a common string, like Taddler.